# Prolog: solving multi-variable arithmetics

Tags: prolog

I am having trouble writing a Prolog predicate that returns the variable values for some arithmetic.

For example, the function should return what x and y can be from the equation: 12 = 3x + 2y.

Currently my code can only work the other way around:

```
foo(S,X,Y) :- 
   S is 3*X+2*Y.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Prolog doesn't have any *functions*. None. Nor can you define your own *functions* in Prolog. It does a fine job with *predicates*, though, both predefined and user-defined. :) Check out the CLPFD library.

Comment: Ideas: check out `library(clpfd)` http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd if you only need integers and `library(clpr)` http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr for dealing with reals. However, I am not sure if `Y=6.0-1.5*X` is a real improvement over `12=3*X+2*Y`, but you should know better what you need.

Comment: From which domain are the values of `X` and `Y` to be drawn? Integers? Rationals? Reals?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the modeling domain you're in, use one of the following:

- [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for integers
- [clpq](/questions/tagged/clpq) for arbitrary precision rational numbers
- [clpr](/questions/tagged/clpr) for limited-precision "real numbers", typically approximated by  floating-point values
- [clpb](/questions/tagged/clpb) for Boolean values

---

Here's how you can handle integers with [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

foo(S,X,Y) :- 
   S #= 3*X+2*Y.
```

Let's look at some sample queries!

First up: ground queries.

```
?- foo(1,23,-34).
true.

?- foo(1,23,-2).
false.
```

Next up: some queries with one-variable.

```
?- foo(X,1,2).
X = 7.

?- foo(1,X,2).
X = -1.

?- foo(1,23,X).
X = -34.

?- foo(1,2,X).
false.
```

Then, a query with one variable used in multiple places:

```
?- foo(X,X,X).
X = 0.
```

At last: some more general queries.

```
?- foo(S,X,2).
S#=3*X+4.

?- foo(S,X,Y).
S#=3*X+2*Y.
```

---

For arbitrary-precision rational numbers, use [clpq](/questions/tagged/clpq):

```
:- use_module(library(clpq)).

?- foo(X,X,X).
X = 0.

?- foo(1,2,X).          % a similar query failed with clp(FD)
X = -5 rdiv 2.          % arbitrary-precision solution

?- foo(S,X,Y).
{Y=1 rdiv 2*S-3 rdiv 2*X}.
```

---

For relations over floating-point numbers, use [clpr](/questions/tagged/clpr):

```
:- use_module(library(clpr)).

foo(S,X,Y) :- 
   { S = 3*X+2*Y }.
```

Sample queries:

```
?- foo(1,2,X).          % a similar query failed with clp(FD)
X = -2.5 ;              % and had an arbitrary-precision solution with clp(Q)
false.

?- foo(X,X,X).
X = 0.0 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go along using the var/1 predicate to check
whether an argument is output:

```
foo(S, X, Y) :- var(X), !, X is (S-2*Y)/3.
foo(S, X, Y) :- var(Y), !, Y is (S-3*X)/2.
foo(S, X, Y) :- S is 3*X+2*Y.
```

Here is an example run with SWI-Prolog:

```
?- foo(S, 1, 2).
S = 7.
?- foo(7, X, 2).
X = 1.
?- foo(7, 1, Y).
Y = 2.
```

Best Regards